# $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ : i.i.d. $\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$. Then $\bar{x}$ is an unbiased estimator of $p$.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

> Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ be i.i.d. $\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$. Then $\bar{x}$ is an unbiased estimator of $p$.

How should I approach for this types of problems.
Some hint will also help me.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Actually independence is redundant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $E(X) = p$ or, for any $i$, $E(X_i) = p$.

So,

$$E(\bar X) = E\Bigl(\frac {\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}\Bigl)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\Big(E{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\Big)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\Big({\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i)}\Big)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}(np)$$
$$=p$$

By the definition of Unbiased Estimator, $\bar X$ is an unbiased estimator of $p$.

Answer (score 2):

If you define $\bar{x}$ as the sample mean, i.e.
$$\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
Take expectations on both sides
$$E \bar{x} = E \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
Since expectation is a linear operator, then
$$E \bar{x} =  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E X_i$$
But since $E X_i = p$, then
$$E \bar{x} =  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n p$$
Since $p$ is a constant, then we could extract it as 
$$E \bar{x} =  \frac{p}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1$$
Now since $\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n$, we get
$$E \bar{x} =  \frac{p}{n}n = p = \mu$$
where $\mu = p$ is the true mean of the Bernoulli distribution, hence we say that $\bar{x}$ is an *unbiased estimator* of $p$, since in average, it gives us $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $X_i$ are Identical. And the linearity property of Expectation.

$E(\bar{X})=E(X_1)=p$